Old client wants files from materials created for them 6 years ago
I had a client who is very rude and condescending. I no longer work for them. I designed their logo and all related print materials 6 years ago in 2018. I just got an email telling me to send them all files related to their logo and print materials.
They were provided all logo designs and materials in 2018 when they used them to create signage and business cards, cheques, etc.
Do I owe them anything? Is there any legal responsibility to keep and give them old files from 6 years ago?

Please don't ask legal questions here. We can't provide legal advice. However, I don't see how you could possibly be held legally responsible for keeping their files unless they have been paying you to store and back up their files, or if it was in your contract with them.  Do you still have the files?

In the UK we are only expected to retain documents relating to a client for two years, (unless they're financial, then it's seven, I believe) and that's only where there is any personally identifiable information contained within.

This question is similar to: Annoying client asks for “all original files” months after project completion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The client was a PITA and probably anything you do will result in more unpleasantness and a waste of your valuable time. You can just tell them they are 'unavailable'.

Top tip: don't detail disagreements with old clients under your real name on the internet :)

If you performed the work, they were satisfied with it, and you were paid then that's it. Any contract, written or implied, has been filled. There's been accord and satisfaction. You owe them nothing.
Unless you specifically state somewhere that you provide ongoing backups for all client files, or are being paid to maintain such an archive, it's not your responsibility to maintain any archive for clients. The client should have backed up files when they were originally sent.
So..

Tell them you no longer have the files.
Tell them you no longer have the files. But you can recreate everything at your current rates (not 6 year old rates).
Tell them you have files, but there's a fee for the time it takes to pull them from archives, and ensure they are in proper form for delivery today given possible technological advances. I'd also point out to the client that even if files are retrieved from an archive that does not mean they will still be in good, usable condition (files can become corrupt).
Just give them the files.
Ignore them entirely.

In broad terms, once a contract has been fulfilled, you are not legally obligated to do anything for a client. Not even obligated to reply to their email.

With all the above written, as a business you really do want to have an archive of past work. If some past client asked me for files 6 years old, I know I have the files - triple redundant backup of all client work since the inception of my business. However, my knowing I have the files may or may not change my response to the client. The archive for my business is not the client's archive. The client should have their own business archive. Failure of the client to maintain their own business archive never means I'm obligated to accommodate any request for files from my business archive.

If the client is smart, they should state that they were responsible and asked for a favor, even offering compensation right off the bat. Contacting you as if you owed them is immediately a red flag and they get ghosted, since they already showed their hand what they will be like.

Noting obviously the possibility that the contract with the client stated that all related materials be provided to them without backup.

Another option, whether you have the files or not, is simply to tell them that you are not in a position to supply files for completed work once it's been handed over. That might imply you simply complete work and forget it, but as Scott says, you're not providing a client archive.

I'm not aware of any business which is inherently expected to retain client files years later so the client can acquire them again. Sure, if it was only a month or two maybe ... but not years. I'm trying to think of any situation where that would be the case. All I can come up with is legal teams, but again, files are typically retained for the law firm not the client. Ask for your dental or medical records, they won't give them to you - even though neither are useful to anyone else. Proprietary historical data belongs to the company, not the client.

@Scott Off the top of my head, various medical services have requirements like that. Tax preparation as well, I believe. Would not be surprised if lawyers may have some (though possibly the courts and public record themselves cover that need). Definitely not anything remotely relevant to this question, though.

See that's the thing @KRyan I know there are requirements for business to retain files (like tax prep and medical) but those requirement may or may not provide for client access to those files. Things like tax prep is a no brainer for them.. they have to maintain the files so providing old tax forms is of no detriment or undue effort to the service. If a client asked me for an email or text file from 6 years ago... sure, if I have it I'll forward it, no problem - it doesn't serve any direct further purpose for me. But design files are a different matter.

@Scott Yeah, that’s why I said “I believe,” I’m not sure what the requirement is for them to provide it to clients—wouldn’t surprise me if there was, but there may not be. I know for a fact that therapists’ notes are legally available to patients, since my wife is one and was trained to keep notes professional since they’re not truly private, even if most patients will never see them. She’s required to keep those notes available for a certain number of years (7, maybe?) in case the patient ever requests them.

If they're rude, and they already got the files before, then:

don't respond, or just say you lost the files
ask for compensation: 6 years of backup costs money, it is like insurance against loss, and also bill for your time managing the situation

